# How can I get an Integer out of a textfield in Xcode 13

Tags: swift, xcode, integer, textfield, xcode13

Hi I am kinda new to Swift and coding at all.
I need the input that the user gave in the textfield as an Integer.
Can someone help me with that problem?

```
  struct FirstView: View {
    @State var score : String = ""
    
    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
            
                TextField("WWhats your score?", text: $score )
                .padding()
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                .onReceive(Just(score)) { newValue in
                    let filtered = newValue.filter {"0123456789".contains($0) }
                        if filtered != newValue {
                            self.score = filtered
                        }
                    }
                }
                    
            }
        }
```

Comment: Instead of all the stuff after `newValue in`, can't you just do `self.score = Int(newValue)`? Or am I misinterpreting the question.

Comment: The stuff below .padding is just to prevent the user from typing in anything other than numbers. My problem is that I need to use the number that the user wrote in the textfield to calculate with it and that is not possible if the number is saved in a sting. Or are my thoughts wrong?